# Unable to connect to arcgis server local

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server

I have ArcGIS Server 10.1 installed and running , and published the services its worked , and setup & Configuration Web Adaptor

when i go the ArcGIS Web Applications for the Microsoft .NET Framework to create new web

i cannot add arcgis server local when i type the host machine Name or "localhost" this message showing

Error: Unable to connect to server

what i can do please

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like possibly DNS/Name Resolution issues. Try using localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I Tried using localhost or 127.0.0.1. don't Respond

Comment: Ok, that is sounding more like a IIS issue; where your webserver is refusing the connection or your permissions for your user are not allowing the connection. Try not using the Local Connection and doing it as a Internet connection but talking to your localhost/127.0.0.1 endpoint.

Comment: thank you very much prof.
i tried your Suggestion , i type the host url services
http://localhost/arcgis/services
using internet server connection , and succeeded the connection

now  how i allowing the connection for local server or user?
And What is the reason for not allowing this 

Thank you for help

Comment: Ok, so that verifies your services are running and available; so your core issue then is going to be your account/access to the local services. As the 'Local' connection is driven by COM+/DCOM technology you can see things like local security policies blocking DCOM connections and services. Using the Rest/Soap endpoints is the easier to manage route to access.

Comment: I have already done so and give allow users using Com security
Thank you very much, and accept greetings

Comment: I study ArcGis server and create web map application depending on myself
your Helper its provided much effort
Thank you...